# How can I easily and efficiently see the available components provided by Angular dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I'm looking at [the tutorial here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Angular-Module-Loading/) (code reproduced below) but this questions applies in any Angular app.

The question is: When I'm either programming an Angular app or looking at someone else's, I'll often see variables used that don't seem to have been declared anywhere. They seem to come out from nowhere and cause a lot of confusion. Of course these variables end up being factories, services, constants etc in the dependencies specified when the app was created.

For example here:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'WelcomeController',
    template: 'views/welcome.html'
  });
})
.config(function(ConnectionProvider) {
  ConnectionProvider.setApiKey('SOME_API_KEY');
})
```

How on Earth, in a large app, would I know that `$routeProvider` came from `ngRoute`, or where did `ConnectionProvider` come from? Also, on the flip side, is there a way to get a quick look at what factories and services are available for use from the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has an internal module `ng` which is initialized at the top of module stack when bootstrapped. In this `ng` module, internal directive/controller/services are registered. But you cannot view that information as Angular keeps it as private property `cacheProvider`. The best way is to read the source code though.

For your own module. you can get a little bit more information by `angular.module('yourModule')._invokeQueue`, everything you defined is kept there with a suffix `provider`